# Adding a CMD line argument to a Variable pointing to a file

Tags: .net

I have a variable in my .NET application that store the location of a file. This variable can change depending on where the users has this file store (It's based on a game installation). Is there any way I can add an Argument to the variable before running it?

Info:

- 'AcesFile' is the Variable which holds the Dir
- The full Dir **Does** hold spaces. I know this has something to do with the structure of arguments.
- The variable always holds this at the end without quotes: "\win64\aces.exe"

I've tried this without success:

Process.Start(AcesFile & "-forcestart")

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can arguments to the variable through a **Main** method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
if (args.Length == 0)
{
System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument.");
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Where would I put this, and how would I ling this to my Var? (I'm still learning a lot about .NET).

This also looks like C+. I'm using VB.NET